# How to do setup/teardown in specs2 when using "in new WithApplication"

Tags: scala, playframework, specs2

I am using Specs2 with play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_51).  I have been reading about how to do setup/teardown with Specs2.  I have seen examples using the "After" trait as follows:

```
class Specs2Play extends org.specs2.mutable.Specification {
  "this is the first example" in new SetupAndTeardownPasswordAccount {
    println("testing")
  }
}

trait SetupAndTeardownPasswordAccount extends org.specs2.mutable.After {
  println("setup")

  def after  = println("teardown ")
}
```

This works fine, except that all of my tests are using "in new WithApplication".  It seems what I need is to have an object which is both a "WithApplication" and an "After".  Below does not compile, but is essentially what I want:

```
trait SetupAndTeardownPasswordAccount extends org.specs2.mutable.After with WithApplication
```

So, my question is, how do I add setup/teardown to my tests which are already using "in WithApplication"?  My primary concern is that all of our tests make use of fake routing like this (so they need the With Application).

```
val aFakeRequest = FakeRequest(method, url).withHeaders(headers).withBody(jsonBody)
val Some(result) = play.api.test.Helpers.route(aFakeRequest)
result
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the code for `WithApplication`:

```
abstract class WithApplication(val app: FakeApplication = FakeApplication()) extends Around with Scope {
  implicit def implicitApp = app
  override def around[T: AsResult](t: => T): Result = {
    Helpers.running(app)(AsResult.effectively(t))
  }
}
```

It's actually quite easy to modify this to suit your needs without creating a bunch of other traits. The missing piece here is the anonymous function `t`, which you provide the implementation for in your tests (using `WithApplication`). It would be nice to make `WithApplication` a little more robust to be able to execute arbitrary blocks of code before and after the tests, if necessary.

One approach could be to create a similar class to `WithApplication` that accepts two anonymous functions `setup` and `teardown` that both return `Unit`. All I really need to do is modify what's happening inside `AsResult.effectively(t)`. To keep this simple, I'm going to remove the `app` parameter from the parameter list, and use `FakeApplication` always. You don't seem to be providing a different configuration, and it can always be added back.

```
abstract class WithEnv(setup: => Unit, teardown: => Unit) extends Around with Scope {
  implicit def implicitApp = app
  override def around[T: AsResult](t: => T): Result = {
    Helpers.running(app)(AsResult.effectively{
         setup
         try {
             t
         } finally {
             teardown
         }
    })
  }
}
```

Instead of simply calling the anonymous function `t`, I first call `setup`, then `t`, then `teardown`. The try/finally block is important because failed tests in specs2 throw exceptions, and we want to be sure that `teardown` will be executed no matter what the outcome.

Now you can easily setup test environments using functions.

```
import java.nio.files.{Files, Paths}

def createFolder: Unit = Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("temp/test"))

def deleteFolder: Unit = Files.delete("temp/test")

"check if a file exists" in new WithEnv(createFolder, deleteFolder) {
    Files.exists(Paths.get("temp/test")) must beTrue
}
```

(This might not compile, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 2):

If your `after` method doesn't need anything from the `WithApplication` trait you can mix in your specification the `AfterExample` trait and define the `after` behaviour for the whole spec:

```
import org.specs2.specification._

class Specs2Play extends org.specs2.mutable.Specification with AfterExample {
  "this is the first example" in new SetupAndTeardownPasswordAccount {
    pending("testing")
  }

  trait SetupAndTeardownPasswordAccount extends WithApplication

  def after = println("cleanup")
}
```

Comment: I like your suggestion, but it doesn't fully work.  The problem is that in setup we have a context for holding data.  The teardown needs to have access to that context.  I have generated user id's, etc, which are only stored within the setup context.  Can you improve it so that the setup/teardown context are the same?

Comment: You can either use a `context` variable and run the spec as `isolated` (so that each example is executed in its own specification class` on run as `sequential` (so that each examples don't step on each other). Otherwise you need to use the other solution to your question (by @LimbSoup)